# How to associate an iframe button click to a window.parent with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, click

I know there are a lot of simular topics on stackoverflow to this, but I have not found one that is specific to my case.  I have an iframe on my same domain, that has a button inside of it.  I have access to it via jquery like this...

```
var mbutton = $('#myframe').contents().find('#login_button');
```

I have also read on several blogs that I can communicate a click event to the parent window like this...

```
$('#button', window.parent.document).click();
```

How do I combine the 2 steps, this way whenever on click (for my iframe button), the button form submits to the parent window? not the iframe window.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 12:36PM**

This would almost make sense to me....

```
mbutton.on("click", function() {
$(this, window.parent.document); 
});
```

...but it doesn't change the parent URL...everything is still occurring in the iframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following process worked for me in sending my iframe source to my parent window. Also, I added a setTimeOut() function just to make sure that the iframe source is fully ready before going to the parent window...

```
var mbutton = $('#myframe').contents().find('#mbutton');
mbutton.click(function(e) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  var mnextwindow = document.getElementById("mwindow").contentWindow.location.href; 
  window.parent.location = mnextwindow;
 },5000);
});
```

Hope this helps someone out